# Reverse of soundex in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, soundex

```
select SOUNDEX('ram')
```

WILL RETURN 'R500'

Is there a way to input 'R500' and return 'ram'

something like this

```
select reverse_of_SOUNDEX('R500')

RESULT
--------
ram
```

Answer (score 3):

You have the same problem as you would have for trying to reverse *any* many-to-one mapping function.

While `ram` may be *one* word that gives you the soundex code `r500`, so do a large number of other words (ran, rim, run, rune, rain and so on, depending on which variant of soundex you're using).

So *which* word would you like to see displayed in that case?

One possibility, if you're after a list of words, would be to populate a table with a large number of words (from a dictionary somewhere) along with their soundex codes. The codes can be set, after insertion of the words, quite easily with:

```
update sxmap set sxcode = soundex(word)
```

and then you can simply do:

```
select word from sxmap where sxcode = 'R500'
```

or:

```
select word from sxmap where sxcode = soundex('ram')
```

Answer (score 2):

A Soundex mapping is essentially a Hash code (i.e a many-to-one mapping).

As such it is not uniquely reversible.

There are several words that can soundex map to `R500`, you cannot tell which was the original before mapping.